# search in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

i am trying to build an application that save data in sqlite database.i have a class that search in the database searching by VendorName and Date. The problem is i want it to display the **MeterNumbers** that was saved on the same **Date** . to what i have tried it only gives me the first result it get in the database, lets say i search for Tom that was saved on 01/01/2013, it supposed to display both metereNumbers of Tom that was saved on 01/01/2013

here is an example of my table in sqlite

> **VendorName**         **Date**      **MeterNumber**
>
> ...Tom.... 01/01/2013 ......2098957438902
>
> ...Tom... 01/01/2013........4786909876785
>
> ...Steven...18/01/2013.........8978978906542

This is the Code in Sqlite database

```
public String getMeterNUmber(String MeterNumber) throws SQLException  
{
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{MeterNumber}; 

Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MeterNumber FROM " + SCAN_TABLE + " WHERE  Date = ?",whereArgs); 
mCursor.moveToFirst(); 


if(mCursor.getCount() > 0){ 
    MeterNumber = mCursor.getString(0); 
}

return MeterNumber;
}
```

this is the code in the class that calls for the query in the sqlite database and take the result to another class by intent

```
Intent updateCustomerIntent = new Intent(Searching.this, Result.class);
updateCustomerIntent.putExtra("product", dbUser.getMeterNUmber(ss));
 startActivity(updateCustomerIntent);
```

Comment: your where argument data is your meternumber?  shouldn't it be the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your getMeterNumber method takes a meter number as an argument, as already pointed out in ggenglish's comment, this seems odd, it should be a date no? Also, your method only calls mCursor.getString(0) once, and then returns that, which means you will only get the meter number from the first row of your result set.

If you want all the results, you will need to iterate over the full recordset. When you receive the cursor, it will be positioned **just before the first row**, so, you can loop through it with the method moveToNext(). Then, you will also have to store your result in a appropriate data structs, such as a ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
    results.add(mCursor.getString(0));
}
```

So, you will end up with something like this

```
public ArrayList<String> getMeterNUmber(String meterDate) throws SQLException  
{
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{meterDate}; 

    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MeterNumber FROM " + SCAN_TABLE + " WHERE  Date = ?",whereArgs); 

    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        results.add(mCursor.getString(0));
    }

    mCursor.close();

    return results;
}
```

And then finally, use putStringArrayListExtra instead of putExtra when adding the data to the intent.

Comment: Maybe add a code example for him, so that he can see how to return a `List` of results?

Comment: can you please add/edit an example so that i can see it because i am lost i do not know where to start.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your parameter should be date not number,Secondly you don't loop through the result you just pull your first record. I think you should revise some good tutorial first at using SQLite with android.Here are some good links that may help.

- [Android SQLite Database and ContentProvider - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#sqliteoverview_listviews)!
- [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting one value you should do this:

```
public String getMeterNUmber(String date) throws SQLException {  

    String meterNumber = null;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MeterNumber FROM " + SCAN_TABLE + " WHERE  Date = ?", new String[]{date} );

    if ( cursor.moveToNext() )  meterNumber = cursor.getString(0);

    cursor.close();

    return meterNumber;

}
```

if you are expecting multiple elements you should loop as mentioned by others

```
public ArrayList<String> getMeterNUmber(String date) throws SQLException {    

    ArrayList<String> meterNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MeterNumber FROM " + SCAN_TABLE + " WHERE  Date = ?", new String[]{date} );

    while ( cursor.moveToNext() )  meterNumbers.add( cursor.getString(0) );

    cursor.close();

    return meterNumbers;

}
```

you specify you are querying by name and date but your example code shows otherwise, hopefully this helps a bit though.